# How to intergrate telethon script into my event loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, telethon, event-loop

I have two bots, one is using `pydle` for IRC, like:

```
async def start_ircbot ():
    try:
        client = MyOwnBot(NICK, 
                       realname=REALNAME,
                       sasl_username=SASL_USERNAME,
                       sasl_password=SASL_PASSWORD,
                       sasl_identity=SASL_IDENTITY,)

        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        asyncio.ensure_future(client.connect(HOST, PORT, tls=True, tls_verify=False), loop=loop)
        loop.run_forever()
        loop.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print (e)
```

and another is using `telethon` for Telegram:

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def my_event_handler(event):
    ...

async def start_client ():
    print ("Telegram monitor started...")
    await client.start()
    await client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Both of them work without problem separately.

Now, I want to integrate both of them, I tried to launch both of them in my `main` function like this,

```
import Notifier

...

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather (Notifier.start_client (), start_ircbot ())

asyncio.run(main())
```

It starts without issue but `my_event_handler` seems never to get new messages. If I swap the order of functions:

```
await asyncio.gather (start_ircbot (), Notifier.start_client ())
```

The script will be stuck at launching, I suspect it has to be something within events loops and tried some different methods but without luck, could anyone shed light on this for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newer Python versions are removing the `loop` parameter from most methods, so you should try to avoid using it. As long as you don't use `asyncio.run` (which creates a new loop) or you don't create a new loop yourself, both libraries should be using the default loop from the main thread (I can't speak for `pydle`, but Telethon does this).

As long as the `asyncio` event loop is running, Telethon should have no trouble receiving updates. You can use `client.loop` to make sure it's using the same loop:

```py
tlclient = TelegramClient(...)
irclient = MyOwnBot(...)

@tlclient.on(events.NewMessage)
async def my_event_handler(event):
    ...

async def main():
    await tlclient.start()
    await irclient.connect(HOST, PORT, tls=True, tls_verify=False), loop=tlclient.tlclient)
    await tlclient.run_until_disconnected()  # similar to loop.run_forever() but stops when the client disconnects

client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```